# DRF - in filter, use field-value instead of default pk / id

Tags: django-rest-framework, query-string

I'm trying to use DRF's filters so that the URL query is like so:

```
/roadname/?road=M5
```

not like so

```
/roadinfo/?road=1
```

I can't seem to do it when I've got a ForeignKey relationship.

I've tried using lookup_field with no luck (although not sure how this would work for multiple filter fields anyway - I don't think that's the answer). I've tried using a get_queryset() method in views as in the second example in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods). A comment I came across suggested that this is bad RESTApi practice - is it? How would a user know to type in '1' to get results for 'M5' in a front-end client?

I've set up two really simple models (and serializers, views, etc.) to try these out as below.

If I use RoadName, I have to type the name into the filter search box (rather than having a dropdown), but the url query is how I want it.

If I use RoadInfo (which has a ForeignField to RoadName), I get a drop down in the filter box, but the url query uses the ForeignKey pk.

My question: How can I set it so that when I use RoadInfo, the query uses the field value rather than the id/pk?

**Models**

```
from django.db import models

class RoadName(models.Model):
    road = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.road)

class RoadInfo(models.Model):
    road = models.ForeignKey(RoadName, on_delete='CASCADE')
    # other data
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.road)
```

**Serializers**

```
from traffic.models import *
from rest_framework import serializers

class RoadNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    road = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = RoadName
        exclude = ('id',)


class RoadInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    road = RoadNameSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = RoadInfo
        exclude = ('id',)
```

**Views**

```
from traffic.serializers import *
from traffic.models import *
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from rest_framework import viewsets


class RoadNameViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """ List of all traffic count Counts """
    queryset = RoadName.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoadNameSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = '__all__'

class RoadInfoViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """ List of all traffic count Counts """
    queryset = RoadInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoadInfoSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Is M5 name of a road ?

Comment: @UmairMohammad yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data **M5** on the `road` attribute of `RoadName` model. It can be filtered by `road__road` from **`RoadInfo`** model.

So, Try  **`/roadname/?road__road=M5`**

Comment: Thank you! That did it. I've amended the `RoadInfoViewSet` class to `filterset_fields = ('road__road',)` so now I can use the field value instead of it's id/pk